# "Add" button disabed when creating a view

Tags: visual-studio, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2022

I want to generate a view or partial view from actionby clicking "Add View" button. But as you can see the button is disabled and I cannot generete anything.

I'm using the latest version of Visual Studio 2022.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to generate a view or partial view from actionby clicking "Add
> View" button. But as you can see the button is disabled and I cannot
> generete anything.

Actually, your Add button is disabled because you have either removed model class /templete value or haven't selected anything which causing the issue.

Most importantly, While selecting view you should take either you should select context model or if there is not relevant model class it should select to `Empty or without model` from the dropdown, other than, your Add button would be disabled.

I have reproduced your issue accordingly as you can see down below:

[image]

How to resolve:

You can follow below steps to include your view:

[image]

Output:

[image]

**Note:** Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-view?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#add-a-view) if you would like to know more details.

Comment: Sir! I've "Model Class" and "Data Context Class" inputs that are also disabled. I don't have template dropdown also.

Comment: What project type have you choosen? I mean share more about your project category.  Asp.net core MVC, Razor page or Blazor or what?

Comment: It's N-layered architecture project.  The UI layer use Asp Net Standart 4.x.x Mvc.

Comment: In visual studio 2022 there shouldn't be any project type of Asp Net Standart 4.x.x Mvc because it should be deprecated. Please try with .NET 6 or 7 project.

Comment: It's a real project so cant change the type of the project. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your response and sharing the concern.